# Pointless 'MIDL_INTERFACE' Macro in winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

After browsing some old code, I noticed that some classes are defined in this manner:

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")
Classname: public IUnknown {
    /* classmembers ... */
};
```

However, the macro `MIDL_INTERFACE` is defined as:

```
#define MIDL_INTERFACE(x) struct
```

in C:/MinGW/include/rpcndr.h (somewhere around line 17). The macro itself is rather obviously entirely pointless, so what's the true purpose of this macro?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Windows SDK version that macro expands to

```
 struct __declspec(uuid(x)) __declspec(novtable)
```

The first one allows use of the __uuidof keyword which is a nice way to get the guid of an interface from the typename.  The second one suppresses the generation of the v-table, one that is never used for an interface.  A space optimization.

Answer (score 4):

This is because MinGW does not support COM (or rather, supports it extremely poorly). MIDL_INTERFACE is used when defining a COM component, and it is generated by the [IDL compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378708.aspx), which generates COM type libraries and class definitions for you.

On MSVC, this macro typically expands to more complicated initialization and annotations to expose the given C++ class to COM.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know MinGW supported COM at all, even if poorly (not that i'm planning on using COM to begin with ;-))

Comment: @nebukadnezzar: I believe you can use COM in a limited way, but you cannot expose new COM types in MinGW. It's also missing several Windows COM headers. I could be wrong about that though -- been a while since I used MinGW. (P.S. Why are you helping the *machines* ? I'm gonna tell Zion...)

Comment: Nevermind about that PS -- I read nebukadnezzar as [Nebuchadnezzar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebuchadnezzar_%28ship%29#Nebuchadnezzar_.28.22Neb.22.29)

Comment: Haha, well, my name is no *hommage* to Matrix.. I swear! :D

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, it's for one of two use cases:

1. It's possible that there's an external tool that parses the files looking for declarations like these.  The idea is that by having the macro evaluate to something harmless, the code itself compiles just fine, but the external tool can still look at the source code and extract information out of it.
2. Another option might be that the code uses something like the [X Macro Trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#X-Macros) to selectively redefine what this preprocessor directive means so that some other piece of the code can interpret the data in some other way.  Depending on where the `#define` is this may or may not be possible, but it seems reasonable that this might be the use case.  This is essentially a special-case of the first option.